# How to solve: Warning XBD100: ItemGroup `XamarinBuildDownloadRestoreAssemblyAar` is no longer supported. Xamarin Android Project

Tags: c#, android

I install from NuGet package manager `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads` and after trying to debug I receive this error:

```
Warning XBD100: ItemGroup `XamarinBuildDownloadRestoreAssemblyAar` is no longer supported.  If your build is failing, revert to an older Xamarin.Build.Download version, or migrate your packages to use the new `XamarinBuildDownloadAndroidAarLibrary` ItemGroup.  If your build is succeeding it is safe to ignore this warning. (XBD100) (WeatherLocationInfo.Android)
```

When I click on the warning send me on file `Xamarin.Build.Download.targets` on this part of the code:

```
<Target Name="_XamarinBuildDownloadAarRestore"
    Condition="'@(XamarinBuildDownloadRestoreAssemblyAar)'!=''"
    DependsOnTargets="_XamarinBuildDownload">
    <Warning
        Code="XBD100"
        Text="ItemGroup `XamarinBuildDownloadRestoreAssemblyAar` is no longer supported.  If your build is failing, revert to an older Xamarin.Build.Download version, or migrate your packages to use the new `XamarinBuildDownloadAndroidAarLibrary` ItemGroup.  If your build is succeeding it is safe to ignore this warning."
        />
</Target>
```

Is there a way to solve the problem ?

Comment: you should add xamarin as tag